# Disable Previous Months in date_select Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a month drop down list so that the previous months of the current year do not appear.
Right now my code is :

```
<%= f.date_select :card_expires_on, :discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :add_month_numbers => true %>
```

it shows me all the months now, but I want to remove or hide the past months..Is there a way?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: there is no way to do this without js.  using js, you are better off using a month picker :)

Comment: hey @jvnill can you suggest me any example or a brief code for js for this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

```
<%= select nil, "name_of_your_model[card_expires_on(1i)]", (Date.today.year..Date.today.year+10).collect { |y| y }, options = {}, id: "card_expires_on_1i" %>

<%= select nil, "name_of_your_model[card_expires_on(2i)]", (Date.today..Date.today.end_of_year).collect { |d| ["#{d.strftime('%m')} - #{d.strftime('%B')}", d.strftime('%m')] }.uniq, options = {}, id: "card_expires_on_2i" %>

<%= text_field_tag "name_of_your_model[card_expires_on(3i)]", nil, type: 'hidden', value: Date.today.day, id: "card_expires_on_3i" %>
```

Basically when you put date_select in your form it creates three selects.  Rails then uses the "(1i)", "(2i)", and "(3i)" to bring the year, month, and day, respectively, back together.  Make sure you change "name_of_your_model" to the name of the model used for the form and the value of the text_field to what ever default day you want.

***Update***

I just tested this and it did work!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you should be able to add this to a helper. I'd shy away from javascript

adding your own method for remaining_months() or some such thing would be much simpler to use.